# Display a UL List Horizontally

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am not sure how to make my Subnav list to display horizontally. Does anyone know how to solve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/nategines/9bued/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward.  The bulk is by floating the li elements to the left:

```
li
    float: left
```

You'll likely want to add some padding and set the list-style to none:

```
ul
    list-style: none

li
    float: left
    list-style: none
```

A few other things like borders, margin, and padding could polish it up but that is essentially it.

Answer (score 0):

Your list container, `#subtabs`, has a width of `10em`, which translates to 160px, the same width of your list items. Increase the width or remove it all together and you should be ok.